# How to empty recent list for an object

Tags: apex, soql, recentlyviewed

I have a user who uses the recent sales invoice list for sending emails.  The process she uses is:

1. View sales invoice
2. Click on billing contact to display the contact
3. Select Activity related list
4. Click the Send Email button
5. Select Sales Invoice from related to list
6. Click the lookup icon and the most recent sales invoice would show on top

Now that her recent list is over 200 items, it doesn't always show the recent SIN in the list.  Is there any way to empty the recent list so the new viewed invoices will show in the lookup?  I don't know if there's a way to just empty recent list for a specific user and object.

Comment: Assuming the "recent list" is a list view, you can login as her and create a different list view with whatever filter criteria. Alternatively you as the admin can create a list view that is visible to all users - see [tutorial](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_customization/lex_customization_list).

Comment: No.  I am talking about the standard 'Recently viewed' list that appears when the tab is first opened before any list view is selected or the go button is pushed.  I found how to access it via soql and I can clear it via the developer's console, but I was looking for a simpler way for the user to do it.

Comment: Right, Recently Viewed is a list view, thus my comment stands. Add another list view that sorts by SIN or some timestamp in descending chronological order so that it shows newer invoices first.